# Using custom string class as map key value in c++

Tags: c++, string, dictionary, key, operator-overloading

When I try to use my custom string class as the key value, I see this error

```
undefined reference to `operator<(DSString const&, DSString const&)'
```

I have overloaded the < operator, but it only allows me to do this with one parameter, not two. I read a question similar to this, but I was unable to get any of the solutions to work.

```
bool DSString::operator< (const DSString& newData){
    bool lessThan = true;
    int counter = 0;
    int dataLetter = 0;
    int newDataLetter = 0;

    //compare each letter of both Strings until they differ,
    while(dataLetter == newDataLetter && counter < this->length){
        dataLetter = static_cast<int>(data[counter]);
        newDataLetter = static_cast<int>(newData.data[counter]);
         //change bool if char of current stirng is greater
        if(dataLetter < newDataLetter)
            lessThan = true;
        else if (dataLetter > newDataLetter)
            lessThan = false;
    }

    return lessThan;
}
```

Comment: "I have overloaded the < operator," How? Please show the code.

Comment: The code for the overload is absolutely critical. Please [edit] the question to add it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your member operator requires that the left-hand side (i.e. the one designated by `this` pointer) is non-`const`. Adding `const` to the declaration will fix the problem:

```
bool DSString::operator< (const DSString& newData) const;
```

Your implementations of the `while` loop is incorrect: the value returned by your operator corresponds to the last comparison result. Correct implementation should return `true` or `false` as soon as the difference is discovered; the loop should continue only if the characters at the corresponding position are identical. In addition, the loop should stop when the end of the *shorter* of the two strings is reached; your current implementation stops when `this` string runs out of characters, causing undefined behavior when the other string is shorter.

[Demo.](https://ideone.com/ZQ0DDk)

Comment: This fixed the error, but now I am seeing " ambiguous overload for ‘operator<’ (operand types are ‘const DSString’ and ‘const DSString’)
       { return __x < __y; }" 
                    ^

Comment: @Alex Do you have another free-standing implementation of the same operator? If you do, remove one of the two implementations, because you need only one of them.

Comment: That was it. One of the solutions I had tried before did not get deleted.

Comment: @Alex Great! If this works for you, consider accepting the answer by clicking the check mark to the left of it.

Comment: I have modified it so it makes sure the counter is small than the length of both of the strings to fix your last suggestion, though I'm not sure what you mean by the first part. The way I am understand my code, it will always do at least one loop as I set the comparison values to 0 (as long as neither string is empty). If the first chars are different, these values will then be different, and the loop will not repeat, and then return true or false based on which char had a higher value. I am not sure how this is different than "return true or false as soon as the difference is discovered;"

Comment: @Alex I see, your implementation would work fine. You can simplify it, though: instead of `lessThan = true` and `lessThan = false` you should write `return true` and `return false`. Remove declaration of `lessThan`, and `dataLetter == newDataLetter` from the `while` loop header.